# Ant doesn't print output in eclipse console

Tags: eclipse, ant

I'm totally new to compiling through ANT. My high level understanding is that I'd just have to compile the build.xml which in turn would compile my JAVA code associated inside the xml and generate whatever output my JAVA code should show up. (I know I might be terribly wrong here. but, please correct me if I am )

To just compile my first build.xml, i wrote the below code for a start.

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World Successful in Ant");
}
}
```

I ran it and it printed the output in Eclipse console. (No surprises)

Now I created an ANT file for the code above through Eclipse (My understanding is eclipse would create the build.xml by itself through right clicking on the project-> Export-> ant build files )which saves me time writing the XML myself.

After this, I ran the build.xml inside eclipse ( Right click on xml-> Run as-> Ant Build ). But the console doesn't print my result. It comes as below.

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\s.w.ramachandran\workspace\HelloWorldAnt\build.xml

build-subprojects:

init:

build-project:

[echo] HelloWorldAnt: 

C:\Users\s.w.ramachandran\workspace\HelloWorldAnt\build.xml

build:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Total time: 452 milliseconds

As per my understanding of ANT so far,compiling an ant xml would basically do whatever that's been written in my JAVA code. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

(Btw, my long term goal is to use the build.xml which would run my Selenium tests through JIRA Test management tool. So that's the reason I got into ant and thought of getting to know how it works and so on )

This is the XML which was created by eclipse.
    
    
              as the first entry and export the buildfile again. -->

Comment: You are expecting the System.out.println("Hello World Successful in Ant") to be output to the console when you run the Ant build?  This is not the case.  Ant will not execute Java code it will compile the code.  You would need to add some unit tests to exercise your java code and add output to the console.

Comment: There are commands you can add to an Ant build.xml file to execute java classes <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="sample" basedir="." default="notify">
   <target name="notify">
      <java fork="true" failonerror="yes" classname="NotifyAdministrator">
         <arg line="admin@test.com"/>
      </java>
   </target>
</project> But longer term you may just want to focus on figuring out how to execute selenium tests from Ant.